# Is there an elegant way to convert from logical indexing to numerical indexing?

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

Suppose `idxl` is an already defined logical array. I would like to find `idxn` as the equivalent numerical array. i.e.

```
v(idxl) = v(idxn)
```

where `v` is an arbitrary vector (with the same size as `idxl`)

For example,

```
idxl = [0 0 1 0 1 0]
```

should produce an output of

```
idxn = [3 5]
```

Is there an elegant way to convert from logical indexing `idxl` to numerical indexing `idxn`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`find`](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html):

```
idxn = find(idxl);

idxn =
 3     5
```